# Show that $f(x,y,z) = 2x-3y+z$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Show that $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y,z) = 2x-3y+z$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Solution Verification Requested**

We want to show that $f$ is continuous at $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.

Suppose $\|(x,y,z) - (a,b,c)\| < \delta$  and let $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$

$$\|f(x,y,z)-f(a,b,c)\| = \|2x-3y+z-(2a-3b+c)\| = \|2x-2a+3b-3y+z-c\|$$

$$\leq \|2x-2a\| + \|3b-3y\| + \|z-c\| < \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} = \varepsilon$$

Comment: You can factor out $2$ and $3$ and might take another $\delta$ like using a common multiple or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. To begin with, let us assume that $\|(x,y,z) - (a,b,c)\|_{2} < \delta_{\varepsilon}$.

Hence we may claim that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
|x - a| \leq \|(x,y,z) - (a,b,c)\|_{2} < \delta_{\varepsilon}\\\\
|y - b| \leq \|(x,y,z) - (a,b,c)\|_{2} < \delta_{\varepsilon}\\\\
|z - c| \leq \|(x,y,z) - (a,b,c)\|_{2} < \delta_{\varepsilon}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Based on such relations, one arrives at the following result:
\begin{align*}
|2x - 3y + z - (2a - 3b + c)| & = |(2x - 2a) - (3y - 3b) + (z - c)|\\\\
& \leq |2x - 2a| + |3y - 3b| + |z - c|\\\\
& = 2|x - a| + 3|y - b| + |z - c| < 6\delta_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If we are using the taxicab metric then

$|2x-2a| + |3b-3y| + |z-c| = 2|x-a| + 3|y-b| + |z-c| \le 3|x-a| + 3|y-b| + 3|z-c| = 3d((x,y,z),(a,b,c)) < 3\delta = \epsilon$

You have a wide choice of metrics to use, so pick the one that is easiest for the task at hand.  But, you should be clear which metric you have chosen.